# Error Occurred while login the management console of WSO2 Identity Server 5.5.0 version

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im getting the following error while login to the management console of Identity server,

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-15 02:39:04,415] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-15 02:39:04,415] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : PRE_AUTHENTICATION
```

I have configured the jdbc user store for the user management. What is issue ?

Comment: If you share the full error log, it will be more helpful to analyze the root cause

Comment: Only this error occurs during the login.

Comment: could you please add the entry "log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin=DEBUG" to log4j.properties file, restart the server and retry the flow and share the full error log?

Comment: Also could you please share the masterdatasources.xml configuration with removing the sensitive information